# JavaScript filtering Object on a property that is an array

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I have the following payload (small sample) being returned from an api as an Object.

```
{
"0hmITkwFMbB2BDIUFlFm": {
    "price": 89,
    "categories": ["wireless", "broadband"],
    "companyname": "T-Mobile",
    "symbol": "TMUS"
},
"8g570i57at8yTjoZtSuk": {
    "companyname": "Microsoft",
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "price": 181.25,
    "categories": ["technology", "software"]
},
"OMc8V4AVH5q5z0Sis8vp": {
    "companyname": "Amazon",
    "symbol": "AMZN",
    "price": 2419.49,
    "categories": ["E-commerce", "consumer products"]
},
```

I want to be able to return each object that includes a given value in the categories array. For example, returning all object that includes "technology" in the categories array.

How can I do this in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const obj = {
"0hmITkwFMbB2BDIUFlFm": {
    "price": 89,
    "categories": ["wireless", "broadband"],
    "companyname": "T-Mobile",
    "symbol": "TMUS"
},
"8g570i57at8yTjoZtSuk": {
    "companyname": "Microsoft",
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "price": 181.25,
    "categories": ["technology", "software"]
},
"OMc8V4AVH5q5z0Sis8vp": {
    "companyname": "Amazon",
    "symbol": "AMZN",
    "price": 2419.49,
    "categories": ["E-commerce", "consumer products"]
}
}

const filteredObjects = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, rec) => {
  if (obj[rec].categories.includes('technology'))
    return [...acc, obj[rec]]
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredObjects))
```

following code allows you to get filtered array of objects, that satisfy your given condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try is

```
let filteredObjects = [];
Object.keys(sampleObjects).map((key) =>{
   if (sampleObjects.indexOf('technology') != -1) {
      filteredObjects.push(sampleObjects[key];
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let response = {
  "0hmITkwFMbB2BDIUFlFm": {
    "price": 89,
    "categories": ["wireless", "broadband"],
    "companyname": "T-Mobile",
    "symbol": "TMUS"
  },
  "8g570i57at8yTjoZtSuk": {
    "companyname": "Microsoft",
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "price": 181.25,
    "categories": ["technology", "software"]
  },
  "OMc8V4AVH5q5z0Sis8vp": {
    "companyname": "Amazon",
    "symbol": "AMZN",
    "price": 2419.49,
    "categories": ["E-commerce", "consumer products"]
  }
}

let newObject = {}

for (const property in response) {
  if (response[property].categories.indexOf("technology") > -1) {
    newObject[property] = response[property];
  }
}

console.log(newObject)
```